# Prove that is always an integer $\frac{p_n!}{p_n(p_n+1)(p_n+2)(p_n+3)\dots(p_{n+1}-1)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p_1<p_2<\dots<p_n<\dots$ be the consecutive primes . Prove that $$\frac{p_n!}{p_n(p_n+1)(p_n+2)(p_n+3)\dots(p_{n+1}-1)}$$ is always an integer except when $p_n=3$ .

---

$\textbf{Attempt:}$ Call the denominator $X$. For any prime $p$ such that $p_1 \leq p \leq p_n$, we intend to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \geq v_p(X)$$ Also, $$X= \frac{(p_{n+1} -1)!}{(p_n -1)!}$$ So, $$v_p(X)= v_p((p_{n+1} -1)!)- v_p((p_n -1)!)$$ So the problem comes down to proving the following inequality: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{p_n-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$ with   $p_1 \leq p \leq p_n<p_{n+1}$. I tried using the fact $$⌊x⌋≤x<⌊x⌋+1$$ but it doesn't work. How do I proceed?

Comment: What exactly is the denominator product ? I ask because the last term does not fit in the general terms before.

Comment: @Peter the product contains all the numbers from $p_n$ to $p_{n+1}-1$ inclusive

Comment: The claim is true for the positive integers $n\le 10^4$ except $n=2$

Comment: @Peter the main problem or my inequality? Also how did you verify?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: I did not check the inequality. But I applied brute force with PARI/GP as a first step to make the conjecture plausible.

Comment: @Peter this problem was proposed to American Math Magazine and I collected this problem from here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h3019224p27134756

Comment: @AnneBauval How do I use Bertrand Postulate to prove my inequality? Also there's a floor function.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I could prove $\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{p_n-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor$ but I can only prove $\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{p_n-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor-1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval how did you prove that? Can you show it please

Comment: Let$$a:=\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p^k}\right\rfloor,\quad b:=\left\lfloor\frac{p_{n+1}-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor,\quad c:=\left\lfloor\frac{p_n-1}{p^k}\right\rfloor.$$
Then,$$a+c\ge\frac{p_n+1}{p^k}-1+\frac{p_n}{p^k}-1>\frac{p_{n+1}+1}{p^k}-2\ge\frac{p^kb+2}{p^k}-2>b-2.$$

Comment: Does American Math Magazine count as contest-math?

Comment: @gist076923 I'm not sure but how is it relevant in the light of the problem?

Comment: To properly tag question

Comment: @gist076923 if you want you can add the tag, but American Math Magazine is not really a contest, but the genre of the problem is definitely of contest maths.

Comment: Is this a known result of a conjecture? Either way I don't see how Bertrand's Postulate is helpful, as the original question implies a bound more stringent than BP. BP gives $p_{i+1} < 2p_i$, but obviously $(2p_i-1)!/(p_i-1)! \gg (p_i!)$ except for $p_n \in \{2,3\}$. So if this is a known result, it's an improvement on Bertrand's Postulate.  Note that for $p_4=7, (7!)/(7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10) = 1$

Comment: Argh, darn lack of edit button, *or*, not *of*. Is this a result *or* a conjecture?

Comment: Inspired by the unfulfilling answer below: if we let the gap function $g_n = p_{n+1}-p_n$, then we can rewrite the expression of interest as: $$(p_n-g_n)! \frac{\binom{p_n-1}{g_n-1}}{\binom{p_{n+1}-1}{g_n-1}}$$

Comment: $p_n$ meaning $n$th prime, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give a proof using that $p_{n+1} < 3p_n/2$ for $p_n >7$ which follows by checking the few primes between $11$ and $23$ from Nagura's result ($p_{n+1} < 6p_n/5, p_n >23$) mentioned on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results

We use the following Lemma:

If $2 \le x \le a$ then $2[\frac{a}{x}] \ge [\frac{3a}{2x}]$, while if $3x \le a$ we have $2[\frac{a}{x}] \ge [\frac{3a}{2x}]+1$.

Let's show how this implies the result and then prove the above Lemma. Assume $p_n \ge 17$ as the result is true for $5,7,11,13$ by inspection

Note that $\frac{p_n!}{p_n(p_n+1)(p_n+2)(p_n+3)\dots(p_{n+1}-1)}=\frac{a!^2}{ab!}$ where $a=p_n, b=p_{n+1}-1, b+1< \frac{3a}{2}$ by the observation above.

Note that the only primes dividing the denominator are $p_n=a, p<a$, and $a$ presents no problem as both numerator and denominator divide by $a^2$ and no higher power.

Fix now $p<a$ a prime. If the highest power for which $p^n \le b$ satisfies $p^n < a$, then the numerator divides by $p^l$ where $l=2\sum_{k=1}^n[\frac{a}{p^k}]$ and the denominator divides by $p^m$ where $m=\sum_{k=1}^n[\frac{b}{p^k}] \le \sum_{k=1}^n[\frac{3a}{2p^k}] $. The Lemma above (with $x=p^k <a, k=1,..n$) shows that $l \ge m$ so all such $p$ are good.

If the highest power for which $p^n \le b$ satisfies $p^n > a$, then clearly $n \ge 2, p^{n-1} \le b/2 <a, 2p^n > 2a>b$ and if $3p>a$ then $a^2/9 <p^2 \le p^n \le  b < 3a/2-1$ so $a^2+9 \le 27a/2$  and that clearly is not possible for $a \ge 17$ which is our situation, hence $3p \le a$.

So now with the notations above, we have that $l=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\frac{a}{p^k}]$ and $m=\sum_{k=1}^n[\frac{b}{p^k}]=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\frac{b}{p^k}]+1 \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[\frac{3a}{2p^k}]+1 $

Since $3p \le a$ the Lemma above with $k=1, x=p$ implies $2[\frac{a}{p}] \ge [\frac{3a}{2p}]+1$ while (if $n \ge 3$) we still have $2[\frac{a}{p^k}] \ge [\frac{3a}{2p^k}], 2 \le k \le n-1$ so again $l \ge m$ hence such $p$ are also good and the number in the OP is an integer.

Proof Lemma:  Let $a=kx+c, 0 \le c \le x-1, k \ge 1$ so $2[\frac{a}{x}]=2k$. Now $\frac{3a}{2x}=\frac{3k}{2}+\frac{3c}{2x} <\frac{3k}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$ since $c/x<1$

If $k$ is odd, then $[\frac{3k}{2}+\frac{3}{2}-\epsilon] \le \frac{3k+1}{2}$ and $2k \ge \frac{3k+1}{2}$ while for $k \ge 3$ (so for $a \ge 3x$) we actually have $2k \ge \frac{3k+1}{2}+1$

If $k$ even then $[\frac{3k}{2}+\frac{3}{2}-\epsilon] \le \frac{3k}{2}+1$ and $2k \ge \frac{3k}{2}+1$ while if $k \ge 3$ (hence $k \ge 4$ since $k$ even in this case) we also have $2k \ge \frac{3k}{2}+2$ so the Lemma is proved and the problem soved!

Answer (score 1):

OK... I think that, with a result somewhat better than Bertrand's postulate, we can make this work out. On the WP page for Bertrand's postulate, we have Nagura's 1952 result that for $n>25$, there is at least one prime in the interval $[n, \frac65 n]$. Hence for $p_i>29$, the gap function $g_i = p_{i+1} - p_i \le \frac p 5$, and $p_{i+1} \le \frac65 p$.

I think that's small enough for proof; it's simple to brute-force prove the claim for $5,7,11,13,17,19,23$.

Let's start by letting $a=p_n, b = p_{n+1}$, getting rid of some annoying subscripts. We can rearrange the expression in the OP as:

$$\frac N D = \frac{a!(a-1)!}{(b-1)!}$$

We'll call the gap function just $g$ here, and we then rearrange further to

$$\frac N D = \frac{a!(a-1)!}{(a+g-1)!} = \frac{a((a-1)!)^2}{(a+g-1)!}$$

We now no longer need to worry about the identity of the next prime; it's sufficient to know that the factorial in the denominator includes no prime numbers greater than $a$. We also know that $g \le \frac a5$.

Now, let's redefine the factorial, because that sounds like a fun, easy, and not-at-all-weird thing to do. Particularly, let's look at the factorial in terms of its prime factorization. If we take the factorial of some integer $n>1$, there will be some number of $2$s multiplied together. Each multiple of $2$ lower than $n$ provides one; each multiple of $4$ provides an extra one; and so on up the powers of $2$. Hence the exponent on $2$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ is:

$$e_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{k \ :\  2^k \le n} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k} \right\rfloor$$

For instance, the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $19!$ is $\left\lfloor \frac{19}2 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{19}4 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{19}8 \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{19}{16} \right\rfloor = 16$. And we can use the same summation for $3,5, \cdots$ all the way up to the largest prime in the factorial. In this way we find $19! = 2^{(9+4+2+1)} \cdot 3^{(6+2)} \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$, which you may easily confirm is correct by throwing `factor(factorial(19))` [into SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=nnebnc).

This means we can express the factorial as a product of powers: $a! = 2^{e_2} \cdot 3^{e_3} \cdots p_i^{e_{p_i}} \cdots a$, where $e_i$ is defined as above.

Then we see that the numerator of our fraction $N = 2^{2e_2} \cdot 3^{2e_3} \cdots p_i^{2e_{p_i}} \cdots a$.

What, then, of the denominator? Well, we know that $a+g-1 < \frac{6a}{5}$. We can therefore say that each of the exponents in the factorization of that factorial--call them $e'_i$--must therefore satisfy $e'_i \le 2e_i$. Most of the exponents will be closer to $\frac54 e_i$, that is, $e_i$ times the limit of ($1 + \frac15 + \frac1{25} + \frac1{125} \cdots)$. But it's likely that one or more exponents on mid-range primes will increase from $1$ to $2$. But very importantly, *no new prime factor can be added*, as there are no primes in $(a,b)$.

Given that the exponents on every prime $p < a$ in the numerator is already $2e_i$, each exponent in the denominator must be equal to or less than its counterpart in the numerator; the exception being that $a$ appears exactly once in both. Therefore, none of the exponents on the primes in this fraction are negative, and the final value of $N/D$ is an integer, for $a \ge 29$, and for $5 < a < 29$, we leave to proof by examination.

---

I think this *may* partially duplicate Conrad's answer above, which was posted a bit after I started writing this (don't worry, I haven't been writing continuously since that, just had a lot of breaks). But I think it goes along a somewhat different line of argument, so I hope it's useful.

Comment: I really appreciate the efforts you put into this. I hope this will benefit every MSers who come looking for this problem. Initially, when I first got this problem, I thought of it as another Olympiad type problem, but this came out to be monstrous. Anyway, thanks a lot to you and others who have put this much time and work to this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

*The proof is not complete as I'm getting too tired to work out the final technical details, but the main ideas should hold true.*

Anne Bauval has already pointed out that $p_{n+1}<2p_n$ following [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) (which is now a theorem). In fact, far stronger bounds are also true.

The poster, Diff_Equations, has already pointed out that it suffices to show that $\nu_p(p_n!)\ge\nu_p((p_{n+1}-1)!)-\nu_p((p_n-1)!)$ for all primes $p\le p_n$ where $\nu_p(x)$ is the number of times $p$ divides $x$.

Given that $p_{n+1}<2p_n$, this is the same as showing that
$2\nu_p(p_n!)\ge\nu_p(p_{n+1}!)$ for primes $p<p_n$. Note that $\nu_p(x!)$ increases proportionally to $x$, so this *almost* follows from Bertrand's postulate.

If we write $x=u_0+u_1p+\cdots+u_m p^m$ in base $p$, we can express
$$
\nu_p(x!) = \sum_{k\ge1}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^k}\right\rfloor
=u_1+u_2(p+1)+\cdots+u_m(p^{m-1}+\cdots+1)
=\frac{x-(u_0+\cdots+u_m)}{p-1}
$$
which gives us
$$
\frac{x}{p-1}-\frac{\ln x}{\ln p}-1
\le\frac{x}{p-1}-(m+1)
\le\nu_p(x!)
<\frac{x}{p-1}.
$$

The above bounds on $\nu$ gives us that
$$
2\nu_p(p_n!)-\nu_p(p_{n+1}!)
>2\cdot\left(\frac{p_n}{p-1}-\frac{\ln p_n}{\ln p}-1\right)
 - \frac{p_{n+1}}{p-1}
=\frac{2p_n-p_{n+1}}{p-1}-2\frac{\ln p_n}{\ln p}-2
$$
where Bertrand's postulate again is *almost* enough.

However, on the [Wikipedia page for Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), stronger results are cited, such as $p_{n+1}/p_n<1+\frac{1}{2(\ln p_n)^2}$ for $n\ge463$. Plugging this in suffices when $p$ is sufficiently small compared to $p_n$.

For $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}<p<p_n$, we have $\nu_p(p_{n}!)=\lfloor p_{n}/p\rfloor$ and $\nu_p(p_{n+1}!)=\lfloor p_{n+1}/p\rfloor$, so
$$
2\nu_p(p_n!)-\nu_p(p_{n+1}!)
\ge\left\lfloor\frac{p_n}{p}\right\rfloor
-\left\lceil\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{p}\right\rceil.
$$
I'm sure there must be some nice way to show that this is non-negative, but right now I end up splitting this into multiple cases.